# My site width breaks on mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

We use a custom template page in wordpress for a narrow width page. My goal is for it to appear as 600px wide + padding of 50px on each side (or so).

This is an example of a page that works on both desktop and mobile:

[edit: removed link]

This is the page with an issue: [edit: removed link] -- it looks correct on desktop, but on mobile isn't scaling down the width. I've tried removing what I thought were likely culprits: the youtube video, reuploading all images w/ 600px width (instead of wordpress resizing), and still having trouble.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this:

Line 6 of main-41ab33da.css

Change "inline-block" to "block", like here

```
.page-template-template-narrow .narrow-landing-page {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

Next, add "max-width" to form (see code) and yellow block (inline styles, as you don't have any selector for it)

```
#lead-capture {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Finally do same for youtube iframe you have and you're good

```
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's great. Maybe you could check the answer as "correct", so other users will see it?